# Xamarin IDE doesn't recognise Resource.Id

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I started following a tutorial on yt 
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZHLHrkvUt0&list=PLCuRg51-gw5VqYchUekCqxUS9hEZkDf6l&index=2)
 but at the point when i have to use Resource.Id, Id becomes red and i can't build the app (a simnple list view).

So what can I do About it ?

Comment: Do you have all the `References,` `using Namespaces` and compiling to the right version of `.Net` as required by `Xamarin`? Are you working with an updated version of `Visual Studio`? It's a bit hard to be specific since its a very general problem which can be caused by various mistakes...

Comment: i have these references: using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Collections.Generic;

Comment: i don't have visual studio, i use the free xamarin IDE

Comment: Ok than I don't want to answer since I've never done it this way but I think it might be your problem, be aware that in that video they use VS as well and I don't know how Xamarin IDE handles resources.

Comment: Try building the project with Resource.Id commented out and see if it is generated after build.

Comment: Ok Thank You guys a lot

Comment: the free xamarin should work ok too, you get this behavior only with Resource.Id? thats a little strange, what does the error says? try to update your Android SDK Manager if this doesnt help reinstall again Xamarin, try also to download another example from the web and see if in other examples Resource.Id works

Comment: I noticed this behavior, when there is a simple error in the axml. Like contradictions in specifications, double specifications, etc. My advice: cut out all item specs, and reinsert them one by one, starting with the android:id, save after each line and verify in the class, when the id becomes red. That's the culprit.